# Absolutely and Relatively free abelian groups.

Tags: group-theory

I see that there are the notions of **absolutely** free abelian group and **relativley** free abelian group. Could you please explain the difference between the two notions. Thanks!!

Comment: Where do you "see" this?

Comment: They are talking about absolutely and relatively free groups the word "abelian" was added by me. Does this mean there is no such notion in the abelian context, and what is the difference between absolutely free group and relatively free group? thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

According to the online [Encyclopedia of Mathematics](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Free_group):

> A free group in a [variety](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Variety_of_groups) $\mathcal D$ of groups  is defined analogously to a free group, but within $\mathcal D$. It is also called a $\mathcal D$-free group, or a relatively-free group (and also a reduced free group).

Presumably, if the variety $\mathcal D$ only consists of abelian groups, then it would be a relatively-free abelian group.

For example, the variety $\mathcal D$ defined by the single relationship $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1$ describes the variety of abelian groups, so a $\mathcal D$-free group would be a standard free abelian group.

If $\mathcal D$ contains more relations, you'd get different classes of relatiely free groups. For example, with the relations:

$$xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1, x^3=1$$

then you'd get the variety of vector spaces over $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$, and the relatively free ones would be the ones with bases (which is all of them, if you use use the axiom of choice.)

The varieties of groups $\mathcal D$ that only include abelian groups are all of the form:

$$xyx^{-1}y^{-1} =1, x^d=1$$

for some integer $d\geq 0$. In this case, the variety is the variety of  $\mathbb Z/d\mathbb Z$-modules. and the "relatively free groups are the free modules.

Comment: So in the category theory language this means that an absolutely free group $G$ is one that is free in every categegory that contains $G$ as an object, while relatively free group is one that is free in a particular category and not free in other categories. For example $\mathbb Z$ is an **absolutely** free group as it is free in the category of groups and the category of free abelian groups. But $\mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z$ is a **relatively** free group since it is free in the category of abelian groups but not free in the category of groups. Is this correct ?

Comment: I didn't see a definition of absolutely free, I sort of assumed it just meant the usual sense of a free group. I suspect that  agrees with your definition, however.